# Importing local go module of external service

Tags: go, go-modules

***The background:***

Two Applications - `A` and `B`

`Application 'A'` contains two go.mod files

`A/pkg/test/go.mod:` (I keep here application specific structures which are gonna be reused by another services willing to integrate)

```
module A/pkg/test
go 1.14
require (
   some_dependencies vx.x.x
)
```

`A/go.mod:` (root module importing pkg/test as local module)

```
module A
go 1.14
require (
   A/pkg/test v0.0.0
)
replace A/pkg/test => ./pkg/test/
```

Now `Application 'B'` would like to re-use `Application's A` pkg/test package by simply importing it

***The Adventage:***

This solution lets any integrating services pull only dependencies of pkg/test module instead of importing whole application A tree

***Current Solution:***

`Application 'B'` imports pkg/test module of `Application 'A'` using following go.mod:

```
module B
go 1.14
require(
   some_dependencies vx.x.x
   A/pkg/test v0.0.0
)
replace A/pkg/test => gitlab.com/A/pkg/test v0.0.0-02345798575346-72cs44671e34
```

Now I really do not like using commit-timestamp_commit-sha approach here.

***The problem:***

I would like to use `TAGS` in order to import A/pkg/test module.
Repository A has a tag, say v2.0.0, created. When I replace `v0.0.0-02345798575346-72cs44671e34` with `v2.0.0`, after running `go mod tidy/download` I am getting following error output:

```
reading gitlab.com/A/pkg/test/pkg/test/go.mod at revision pkg/test/v2.0.0: unknown revision pkg/test/v2.0.0
```

***The question:***

I assume bad package naming/module naming/tagging etc. might lead to such error. The question is what am I missing here in order to make it clear and work?

Comment: besides the answer below, please read/understand the implications of [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/) - so never start with `v2` - but `v0` and slowly migrate to a mature state of `v1`. `v2` indicates a breaking change that is incompatible with all previous versions - so that switch should be taken very seriously - [read more here](https://blog.golang.org/v2-go-modules).

Comment: Note that your advantage isn‘t one.

Comment: @colm.anseo I am aware of that, but thank you for pointing it out and sending over a nice article - might be quite useful for anyone dealing with similar issue

Comment: @Volker would you mind elaborating on how it is not an advantage? This is basically main reason I decided to design it like that and would love to hear counter point.

Comment: @Power Dependencies are cheap. Especially test dependencies which are not compiled into your binary. Go is not Node.

Comment: @Volker 'test' was just a placeholder name. Normally, what lies under pkg/{package_name} is some common code that would be used across the platform that I am working on currently. Dependencies being cheap doesn't mean they cannot be optimized in terms of size, hence I strongly disagree with  you claiming that such solution doesn't bring any adventage.

Answer (score 0):

To take a nested go-modules package within a git repo, just add a tag to the directory that contains the `go.mod` file - and then append your version.

So in your case, the directory is `A/pkg/test` and lets say you wanted to use semver `v0.0.1` you tag like so:

```sh
git tag -a "A/pkg/test/v0.0.1" -m "initial test checkin"
git push origin --tags                            # push all local tags
# git push origin "A/pkg/test/v0.0.1"             # push a single tag
```

---

**Please Note:** from the Go wiki [Should I have multiple modules in a single repository?](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#should-i-have-multiple-modules-in-a-single-repository) - Russ Cox (the creator of `vgo` i.e. today's go-modules) warns:

> For all but power users, you probably want to adopt the usual
> convention that one repo = one module. It's important for long-term
> evolution of code storage options that a repo can contain multiple
> modules, but it's almost certainly not something you want to do by
> default.

---